# Escreva um programa que leia um caractere e mostra o valor booleano True (verdadeiro) se for um dígito entre ‘0’ e ‘9’ se não False (falso)

Tags: python, operadores, condição

```
def cont(caracter):
    digito = ord(caracter)
    return digito == 0 or digito == 9

def main():
    usuario = str(input())
    print(cont(usuario))
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Onde está o erro nesse código?

Comment: Creio que a questão pede **entre** 0 e 9 e não igual a 0 ou igual a 9. Tente `digito >= 0 and digito <= 9`. Não entendi a utilização da função `ord`, não bastaria um `int(caracter)`?

Comment: `input` já retorna uma string, então `str(input())` é redundante e desnecessário. Faça apenas `input()` que é suficiente para ter uma string

Comment: Vale lembrar também que `ord` dará erro se a string tiver mais de um caractere, então uma sugestão seria verificar o tamanho da mesma (`len(caracter)`) ou capturar o `TypeError`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há alguns erros, e algumas coisas complexas demais.

Você está transformando o caractere digitado no número dele na tabela que determina quais são os caracteres (ASCII ou Unicode). Então tem que comprar com esse número e não o número equivalente ao caractere. Talvez nem era o que queria fazer, mas já que fez eu mantive isso, só comparei agora com os números da [tabela](http://www.asciitable.com/) para ficar correto (48 é o caractere 0 e 57 é o 9). Interpretei que a faixa é totalmente inclusiva, mas a pergunta não deixa isso claro.

Outro problema é que está verificando só as pontas, o primeiro ou o último, e os números que estão no meio disso, onde compara? Então mudei o operador para comprar uma faixa de números. Tem outras formas de fazer isso.

Tirei algumas coisas que não são necessárias, e mudei o nome da função porque `cont` não quer dizer nada.

Não resolvi todos problemas disso, leia comentário do hkotsubo. Se não quer que dê erro teria que fazer validações, até mesmo se mudar a forma de conversão de valores. Até porque toda entrada de dados deveria ser validada quando há restrições do que pode digitar.

```
def verifica_digito(caractere):
    digito = ord(caractere)
    return 48 <= digito <= 57

print(verifica_digito(input()))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/RtNHpM). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/prqabdwt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/RangeVerification.py).

Comment: consegui, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser feito com **conversão para inteiros** também. Fiz algumas modificações no código para tornar simples. Veja que a função agora retorna **True** ou **False** dependendo do que foi digitado.

```
def cont(number):
return number > 0 and number < 9

print(cont(int(input())))
```